# command to wake up the windows system after sleep command

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, sleep

From C# program I want to call windows command prompt and make the system to sleep and after few seconds I should wake the system. I am successful in making the system sleep but I can't wake it up after few seconds. The command that I tried for making it sleep and wake up is "powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0 && timeout 10 && echo "Hello World" ".

The link http://www.groovypost.com/howto/schedule-wake-sleep-windows-automatically/ says echo will wake the system but its not working.

Comment: Your command will never work as sleep and wake need to be separate tasks. If you read the articke you linked to you will see two different **scheduled tasks**, one to sleep and the other to wake.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the computer sleep and then waking it up?

Comment: Not **in the same** command. And once it is asleep the only way to wake it up is from a scheduled task. The link **explains this** "There isn’t really a command line command to wake your computer. That’s because if you are in a position to be running commands, then your computer is obviously already awake. "

Comment: As above, computers can't run commands when asleep. You'll have to research using wake-on-timer aka wake-on-rtc

Comment: scheduled task to wake the system is available only in GUI, not in comment prompt

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the win32 CreateWaitableTimer API.

- The process that creates the WaitableTimer has to be alive when the system sleep is called.
- Example uses pywin32 api.
- Allow timers to wake system from sleep in your Windows power configuration.

```
    from win32event import CreateWaitableTimer
    from win32event import SetWaitableTimer
    from win32event import WaitForSingleObject
    import sys

    def main(minutes):
        minutes = int(minutes)
        handle = CreateWaitableTimer(None, True, 'Wake up')
        dt = -10000000 * minutes * 60 # Convert to seconds.
        SetWaitableTimer(handle, dt, 0, None, None, True)
        rc = WaitForSingleObject(handle, 1000 * (minutes + 1) * 60) # 11 s.
        print ("Done")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        minutes = sys.argv[1]
        main(minutes)
```

For running the above script call wakeupWindows.py from console like:

```
python wakeupWindows.py 2
```

Will set the wake up timer to 2 minutes from now. 
The script will wait for 2 + 1 = 3 minutes. 
From another console put the system off to sleep using:

```
shutdown /h
```

After 2 minutes, the system will wake up from sleep.

Similar implementations are possible using C# or this script can be converted to an exe using pyinstaller as explained [here](https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script/).

Comment: Didn't work for me, `SetWaitableTimer` fails with "not supported" error.