# Wake Windows PC from sleep in Python 2.7

Tags: python, sleep, wakeup

I have a script that will put the system to sleep in the middle of it. Is there any way to make that script wake the system up and then continue running?

I have read many round-about ways of doing so by Wake on LAN or using Task Scheduler. I am looking for something that would wake it up after a set period of time or after a specific piece of my script is finished. I will need to this to work for Windows 7, 8.1, and 10.

Anyone know of a way to wake from sleep while still running a script?

Comment: How will the script wake the system up, when the system isn't running the script because it's asleep? How will "a specific part of the script" ever finish, when it's not running because the system is asleep?

Comment: Why do you have to put the computer to sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to accomplish this using just python. However in the Windows SDK they provide a tool called pwrtest that will allow you to do timed sleep cycles. I am able to call this with python and then my script continues when pwrtest wakes the PC up from sleep.

Comment: For future reference, I have posted an example using python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243194/command-to-wake-up-the-windows-system-after-sleep-command/48783158#48783158)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you're putting the system to sleep. If using [`SetSuspendState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (with the last argument being `FALSE` to allow wake-up events), then you can schedule a future wake-up using [`CreateWaitableTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) followed by [`SetWaitableTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The respective Python implementation is quite easy using ctypes or, if you want something more *pythonic*, pywin32.

Hope it helps!